# Deck of Cards placed in structs

Tags: c++

I want to create a struct with the deck of card in it however I don't know how I would do it. Since I'm trying to make both face and suits an `int` value and when calling for example `face = 3` and `suit = 1` it would give me: 3 of Diamonds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct cards {
    char suit[];
};


int main() {
     cards type = {
    '0','1','2','3','4'

 };

  cout << type.suit << endl;


}
```

I know this is wrong, I don't know how to do this...

Comment: You will not get an answer this way. Showing what you tried already with an actual error would.

Comment: You seem to have answered the question in your question.  If your suggested approach is not working for some reason ask about that specifically.

Answer (score -1):

from your original code:

```
const std::string suit[] = {"Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs"};
const std::string facevalue[] = {
    "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
    "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
};

struct card
{
    card(int index)
    : suit(index % 4)
    , rank(index % 13)
    {}

    int suit;
    int rank;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const card& c)
{
    return os << facevalue[c.rank] + " of " + suit[c.suit];
}
```